# Trying to open a relative path in Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: c, file, ubuntu, io

I'm trying the open a relative path in Ubuntu , but after opening the first folder - called `14` - the code fails to open the folder inside - called `15`:

```
int pathsCtr; // number of folders in RelativeArray

char ** RelativeArray; // the folders in the relative path, currently: 

RelativeArray[0] = "14";

RelativeArray[1] = "15";
// some code before 

if (pathsCtr > 0 && flag == TRUE) // then we have a relative path
{
    int j = 0;
    while (j < pathsCtr)  // run until the last path and open every one
    {
        printf("\n%s\n" , RelativeArray[j]);
        dirp = opendir(RelativeArray[j]);  // open all directories until the last one
        if (dirp == NULL)
                return -1;
        j++; // proceed to the next directory
    }

    flag = FALSE; // turn off the flag , we'll never go near this again
}
```

When `j == 0` this line : `dirp = opendir(RelativeArray[j]);` works and `dirp` is not `NULL`.

But when `j == 1` that line `dirp = opendir(RelativeArray[j]);` fails and `dirp` is `NULL` .

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Assume that I'm doing malloc for `RelativeArray` before the above code .

Comment: Fails how? Just doesn't change directory or errors or ???

Comment: @Basic: When `j == 1` the code return `-1` , e.g `dirp` gets `NULL`

Comment: Chris' answer is good, but also note that you don't want to overwrite dirp: it allocates resources for a `DIR`, and should be freed up with `closedir`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

opendir() opens a directory for reading its contents, but it does not change the working directory of the process.

To access a subdirectory, you will have to specify it by its fully path relative to the current working directory (or else its absolute path).

You can probably do this by concatenating your strings with an appropriate separator character.

Since you don't seem to do anything with the directory stream pointer returned by opendir() other than check that it's non-null, there's a good chance this is not the function you want to be using.  You may want to look at chdir() instead (man 2 chdir) but do think about any undesired consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . The thing is that my code ,my actual code , is working perfectly with absolute-path (I'm working on a "find a file project" , when given (1)a path and (2) a filename , I need to check all the sub-directories for that file . But ,when I hit a relative path ,the code fails . So the above code is used for reaching to the "starting point" ,and start the search for the file from there . Do you have a better idea maybe ? thanks again !

Comment: 'man 3 readdir' and 'man 3 scandir' may be of interest.  Or you could figure out how to use the existing find command, perhaps via one of the exec functions.